# Authenticate as admin to Cognito using Lambda IAM Role

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to use the SDK to perform admin actions on my Cognito user pool from my Lambda function, but I cannot work out how to authenticate as admin correctly. Ideally, I'd like to just the execution role that my function is already using but I have not managed to make that work yet and am not sure if it is even possible. If it is possible, what do I need to do to make it work? If it is not possible what is the correct way of achieving this? Do I have to create an admin user in the user pool and then authenticate using a username and password?

Edit: I have implemented Matt's advice with the below code but I am just getting an empty object back from Cognito (literally just {} is appearing in the logs) and I am not sure why. From reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property) I should be getting either data or err. The update is taking place so I know that it's working, I was just expecting to get a confirmation back, does anyone know if I should be getting something back?

```
let cogUser;

const params = {
    UserAttributes: [{ 
        Name: "email",
        Value: args.input.email
    }],
    UserPoolId: context.userpool_id,
    Username: context.user
};

log.debug('Cog user params: ', params);

try {
    cogUser = await context.conns.cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params).promise();
} catch(err) {
    log.error('Coguser threw error: ', err);
}

log.debug('Coguser return: ', cogUser);
```

Edit 2: Attempted using callback instead of promises.

```
context.conns.cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err) 
    } else {
        cogUser = data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the IAM role already tied to the Lambda function, you can just edit the role in the AWS Console and add the proper policies on the role (depending on what you're trying to accomplish).

For example, you could just add the pre-configured "AmazonCognitoPowerUser" policy to the role (see below):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders",
                "sns:ListPlatformApplications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or better, add the specific policy rules needed on the specific resources that your lambda function needs as a new policy instead.

Once you do this, you can call the Cognito Admin APIs directly (see example below):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

    var params = {
        UserAttributes: [{
            Name: `custom:${event.attribute}`,
            Value: event.value
        }],
        UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_example',
        Username: event.username
    }

    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) }
        context.done(null, data);
    });
};
```

Comment: That has helped a lot thank you, do you have any ideas with regards to the follow-up question I have posted as an edit?

Comment: What happens when you use a callback (as shown in the docs) instead of the await/promise?

Comment: Just tried it, see edit to the original post, the return is still empty.

Comment: It is probably getting to your log.debug statement before the callback is done in that case. Try doing it exactly like I have above and see if that works for you.

Comment: Copy pasted your code and got an empty object again. I'll go and ask on the issues page for the SDK for some clarification and improved documentation I guess.

Comment: It has been a while since I looked at this, and I think that code has changed in the meantime so I can't go and check. But I think that an empty object is just what you get returned when it works and I was misreading the documentation.